# pkg.remove не удаляет приложение

Tags: saltstack

Есть SLS фаил собственного написания. Установка работает как положено, приложение ставиться миньен возвращает все как положено. Но вот при попытки удалить то же приложение использую метод remove, миньен возвращает ошибку.

> [ERROR   ] An un-handled exception was caught by salt's global exception handler:
>   KeyError: '8.3.10.2667'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\salt\bin\Scripts\salt-call", line 11, in  salt_call()
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\scripts.py", line 400, in salt_call client.run()
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\cli\call.py", line 57, in run  caller.run()
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\cli\caller.py", line 134, in run ret = self.call()
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\cli\caller.py", line 212, in call ret['return'] = func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\modules\win_pkg.py", line 1638, in remove
>       # Get the uninstaller
>   KeyError: '8.3.10.2667'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\salt\bin\Scripts\salt-call", line 11, in   salt_call()
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\scripts.py", line 400, in salt_call client.run()
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\cli\call.py", line 57, in run caller.run()
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\cli\caller.py", line 134, in run ret = self.call()
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\cli\caller.py", line 212, in call ret['return'] = func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\modules\win_pkg.py", line 1638, in remove
>       # Get the uninstaller
>   KeyError: '8.3.10.2667'

Содержание SLS файла такое

```
1c_32_asb:
  '8.3.10.2267':
    full_name: '1C:Предприятие 8 (8.3.10.2667)'
    installer: '//srv-fs/install/1c/8.3.10.2667/windows/x32/1CEnterprise_8.msi'
    install_flags: '/qn /norestart /la d:/loginstall1c.txt TRANSFORMS=1049sph.mst DESIGNERALLCLIENTS=1 THINCLIENTFILE=0 THINCLIENT=0 WEBSERVEREXT=0 SERVER=0 CONFREPOSSERVER=0 CONVERTER77=0 SERVERCLIENT=0 LANGUAGES=RU'
    uninstaller: '//srv-fs/install/1c/8.3.10.2667/windows/x32/1CEnterprise_8.msi'
    uninstall_flags: '/qn /norestart /la d:/loguninstall1c.txt'
    reboot: False
    msiexec: True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была довольно проста как выяснилось после нескольких часов отладки. Вторая строка в SLS файле, а именно '8.3.10.2267' указывает на неправильную версию должно быть '8.3.10.2667'. Если вдруг возникнет такая же проблема смотрите внимательнее на версии. Возможно кому то это в будущем поможет.